# Whether only have to change the web server's root page configure(such as DocumentRoot) then we can change the domain direct?

Tags: html, apache, web-services

I see a backend system, its function is attractive, especial it can control the frontend template(not only css, it include the html).

[image]

(the templates in the backend system can be downlowd)

Because the web server such as Apache, they are use document root to show the index page of a website. Such as:

```
DocumentRoot "D:/webRoot/default/"  # the website root
```

the `default/` is the default project, and if I download another website(the green site), we must change the Apache's DocumentRoot to:

```
DocumentRoot "D:/webRoot/green_project/"
```

Whether only have to change the web server's root page configure(`DocumentRoot`) then I can get this effect? 
Is there other ways to get this effect?

Or I am wrong, the function not as my thinking at all?

---

**EDIT**

To make a long story short, I see a website backend, which can change the website frontend template easily, I am not sure how can this function implement, I think this is to change the webserver document root, then can do it, such as apache, change the DocumentRoot configuration, then can realize it, whether my think is right?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see here, I would say the simple answer is Yes.

A few points to consider:

1. Are you running multiple websites on 1 Apache server? Then you need to use the virtual host feature and modify http.confd as appropriate. That way changing the document root in this tool will not impact every site on that server.
2. Is this backend only running 1 site?  If yes, then from the information provided you are set.
3. If you want the backend to run multiple sites, then you will need to carefully read their documentation to determine if and how to do that.